# php ssh2_shell, how to resize shell

Tags: php, shell, libssh2

Is there any way, how to resize [ssh2_shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-shell.php) in PHP ?

Comment: did you try what it says there? `[, int $width = 80 [, int $height = 25 ` I'm guessing width and height means something

Comment: :D I want to resize already opened shell...

Comment: Maybe you could use phpseclib? idk if it supports on-the-fly width / height changes but if not you could create a ticket on it's github account asking for that feature. I've found the developer of it to be quite accommodating to such things.